# Optimizing over norms of set of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces

I have a set of N real-valued finite-dimensional vectors $\mathbf{v}_i$ and target norms $y_i$ and I am trying to find a linear transformation matrix $L$ such that the norm of the transformed vectors $L\mathbf{v}_i$ are close to the desired norms. I am now trying to do this with SGD by optimizing the following error function:

$\sum_{i=1}^N \tfrac{1}{2}(y_i - \| L \mathbf{v}_i \|)^2$,

But this is essentially solving a set of equations $\|L\mathbf{v}_i\| = y_i$. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I've edited the question somewhat. The vectors are $D$-dimensional and real valued. $D$ is usually 128 (SIFT descriptors) but can be less or more, I'm looking for a general solution. (In the same application all the vectors have the same dimension of course.) Further, for $L$ I'm looking for a triangular or symmetric matrix such that $M = L L^T$ defines a metric $d(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v'})_M = \sqrt{(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v'})^T M(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v'})}$. I didn't include this in the question because it is a lot of information which is not directly related to the general problem.

Comment: Oh yes, I might have misunderstood the concept of projection. I'll change the question to reflect this. Could I call $L$ a transformation or is this also confusing?

Comment: Any matrix defines a linear transformation of the space. Conversely, every linear transformation is represented by a matrix, once we chose a basis. // Only very special linear transformations are called [projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)). // Yes, if you just want $L$ to be a linear transformation, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7793/discussion-between-cvw-and-5pm)

Comment: I'm on a mobile device now, so chat isn't a good option. Now that the statement is clear, there is an easy special case: if the given vectors are linearly independent, you can send them to any other  linearly independent set, for example into $y_i\mathbf e_i$. But I guess this is not the case for you. Is the number of vectors $N$ greater than the dimension $D$?

Comment: The vectors are not linearly independent, N >> D.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is  clear now. I deleted my earlier comments since they are no longer relevant. Since there is probably no exact solution $\|L \mathbf v_i\|=y_i$, least square minimization looks like the right thing to do. One possibility to consider is to use a different error function $E_2=\sum (y_i^2-\|L \mathbf v_i\|^2)^2 $. This  has the potential advantage of being a polynomial (no square root). If you are concerned that $E_2$ gives priority to longer vectors, consider $E_3=\sum (y_i^{-2}\|L \mathbf v_i\|^2-1)^2$, which operates with relative errors (and is still a polynomial).

Comment: Are you looking for a closed-form solution, code ... ?

Comment: I'm now using least squares and SGD which can take quite a few iterations to get a good answer. But because it seemed so similar to a set of linear equations I thought there might be a way to rewrite it to get a very efficient or closed-form solution.

Comment: There is no way around the fact that the presence of norms makes this a nonlinear problem. The polynomial versions I suggested might be better in terms of convergence, since their derivatives behave nicer.